# Generate a html button from a javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, ejs

I'm struggling with the logic here and hope someone can help. I'm looping through the list array and then through the followers array inside it. I then check to see if the user variable is inside this followers array. The problem is that I want to produce an UNFOLLOW button when the user is in the array and a FOLLOW button when they're not.

What's happening now is that when the followers array has more than one value the loop is going back through it and giving both a FOLLOW and UNFOLLOW button in the one div.

I'm not sure if my logic is off or the syntax.

```
var user ='b';

lists = [
      username: 'pat',
      password: '***',
      followers: ['a','b','c']

    ];
     <% for (var i = 0; i < lists.length; i++) { %>
            <div class="col-xs-4 panel">

        <% for (var j = 0; j < lists[i].followers.length; j++) {%>

            <% if (lists[i].followers[j] == userId) { %>

              <button>Unfollow</button>



              <% } else { %>

                <button>FOLLOW</button>

              <% } %>

        <% } %>

    </div>  
     <% } %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, I think this is what you want:

```
var user ='b';

lists = [
      username: 'pat',
      password: '***',
      followers: ['a','b','c']

    ];
     <% for (var i = 0; i < lists.length; i++) { %>
            <div class="col-xs-4 panel">

        <% for (var j = 0; j < lists[i].followers.length; j++) {%>

            <% var found = false;
               if (lists[i].followers[j] == userId) { 
            %>

              <button>Unfollow</button>



              <% found = true;
                 break;
              }
           }
           if (!found) { %>
              <button>FOLLOW</button>

        <% } %>
    </div>  
     <% } %>
```

Comment: What I need is one button only, and depending on whether the user is in the array or not. As it is it's producing a button for each index of the followers array. I tried moving the closing div about but not having the desired effect. Leads me to think my logic is off.

Comment: OK I see what you're trying to do. I'll keep working on this as in it's current form it's crashing, I knew my logic needed more work.